# perl regex period matches zero length character

Tags: regex, perl

For example:

```
$ perl -pe 's/(.)\G/{$1}/g'
abcd
```

and the result is:

```
{}{a}{b}{c}{d}
```

the first period(.) match is zero length. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: which version of perl are you using?

Comment: @pavel: This is perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for i686-cygwin-thread-multi-64int

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me the result is "abcd", because `/(.)\G/g` can never match — how can it match a single character *before* the current position, starting at the current position? `s/\G(.)/{$1}/g` on "abcd" produces "{a}{b}{c}{d}", which is expected.

Comment: Hmm.. What version of perl do you use?

Comment: @qpfjvn same result with 5.8.8, 5.12.3, 5.14.1

Comment: I have a copy of 5.10.1 here and it returns `{}{a}{b}{c}{d}` so this is probably a bug with 5.10.1

Comment: https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=69056 seems to be relevant — it indicates that `/(.)\G/` would *crash* on 5.10.1, but either way, the fix was to make sure that it doesn't match at all on 5.12+